# Getting unexpected output for test case

Tags: c++

Codeforces problem 372A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/372/A

I am getting incorrect output for test case.Input:

8
2
5
7
6
9
8
4
2

Correct answer is 6.I'm getting 2.

My solution:

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n,size[500000],i,j,noofkangaroo,temp;
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>size[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) //Bubble sort.
    {
        for(j=0;j<(n-i-1);j++)
        {
            if(size[j]>size[j+1])
            {
                temp=size[j+1];
                size[j+1]=size[j];
                size[j]=temp;               
            }
        }
    }
    noofkangaroo=n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((size[j]>=(2*size[i]))&&(size[j]!=-1)) //size[j]=-1 implies that kangaroo can't keep a kangaroo but can be kept by one.
            {
                noofkangaroo--;
                size[j]=-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<noofkangaroo;
}
```

Comment: Statements after `break;` wont be executed. Try placing `size[j]=-1` before break statement.

Comment: @asif-I corrected that.Made a few other corrections.Now I'm getting wrong answer for test case 1.

Comment: That means, you didn't actually solved the problem. you just managed to match some test cases. Try to approach the problem differently. With the given limits, I think, bubble sort will cause a "Time Limit Exceeded" error. Try using STL `sort` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the your code with some tracing added:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n,size[500000],i,j,noofkangaroo,temp,num;
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>size[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) //Bubble sort.
    {
        for(j=0;j<(n-i-1);j++)
        {
            if(size[j]>size[j+1])
            {
                temp=size[j+1];
                size[j+1]=size[j];
                size[j]=temp;               
            }
        }
    }
    noofkangaroo=n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        j=i+1;
        while(j<=n)
        {
            if(size[i]==-1)
            { //Implies that the kangaroo is already keeping a kangaroo.
              num++;
              break;
            }
            if(size[j]>=(2*size[i]))
            {
                noofkangaroo--;
//                cout<<noofkangaroo<<endl;
//                size[j]=-1;
                break;
                size[j]=-1;
//                cout<<size[j]<<endl;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      cout<<size[i]<<endl;

    cout<<noofkangaroo<<endl;
    cout<<num;
}
```

By adding some trace code it shows that the `if(size[i]==-1)` statement is not being executed. That is apparently because of what @asif said in his comment that the `size[j]=-1` is not being executed.
Here is the output for the test numbers on the codeforces web site plus the array numbers printed out, and lastly the value of the trace counter `num` that I added:

```
8
2
5
7
6
9
8
4
2
2
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
5
0
```

The 5 as the next to last number is correct for the number of kangaroos but the 0 at the end (and the values in the array) shows that you are not setting the array values to -1 like you intended. Loops with breaks may not be the way to go with this problem. Happy Sunday!